# How to scrape a restricted webpage using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am wondering if there's any way to scrape html from a restricted webpage using Python.

I have been able to perform login on a webpage but I want to scrape another page after login but the URL says of the page is of the pattern: `main_url/Restricted/Index.aspx`

I haven't been able to get the HTML of the whole page other than the part which is not restricted. How can I get the whole HTML of the restricted webpage?
Here's my code so far:

```
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.request import urlopen
from requests import Session

payload = {
    'username': "username",
    'password': "password"
}

login_URL = 'https://www.something.com/login'

request_url = 'https://www.something.com/overview'

with requests.Session() as session:
    post = session.post(login_URL, data=payload)
    r = session.get(request_url)
    print(r.text)
```

Appreciate the answers.

Comment: Try snooping on what your browser does to fully retrieve the page using e.g. Telerik Fiddler. Chances are the second part is retrieved by javascript in the first part, which the browser executes - solutions are to use a browser emulation, or perhaps to code making the second request (using the session, so cookies are maintained). It’s very unlikely to be anything to do with proxies.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use proxies. Using proper strong proxies you can bypass security mechanism of websites but it also depends of types of security also.

As in above answer said that you should pass cookies also if needed.

pls provide more information on how are you scraping. pls share code also.

Comment: I am unconvinced - why and hw does using a proxy change what the OP’s code gets?